# Create-react-app linting warning after downgrading back to 3.2.0 from 3.3.0

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I upgraded to the latest create-react-app (3.3.0) but had issues locally due to a [known issue with proxying](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8094) in 3.3.0.

After downgrading back to 3.2.0 with the command `npm install --save react-scripts@3.2.0`, I see an error with a dynamic import:

```
./src/App.js Line 28:9: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions
```

The line in question:

```
import(`tenants/${tenant.slug}/TenantData`)
  .then(data => { ... })
```

This has worked perfectly since dynamic imports were introduced in React. I also see a different warning in the browser:

```
SecurityError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': An insecure WebSocket connection may not be initiated from a page loaded over HTTPS.
```

Again, this worked perfectly until I attempted the 3.3.0 upgrade.

I have tried clearing npm cache and removing all package-lock.json files and removing my global node_modules folder.

Comment: Did you try to use `--save-exact` Thats what official release documentation says about updating: `npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@3.3.0`. Maybe you can downgrade the same way.

Comment: I had tried this and it didn't work, but it does seem likely that my problem is a cached module or global module somewhere, so I switched to using NVM, then ran this command and it has partially solved my problem - I can now see that I am for sure running 3.2.0. However, I still see the linting error - I'm wondering if the eslint config is different somehow?

Comment: Can you not just revert to a previous commit? Or clone the project again (without the update ofcourse)?

Comment: that's the weird thing - that code hasn't changed in months, part of the problem was a bad or old module held somewhere, which seems to be resolved. But that line is still triggering a linting error.